# Converting the Create Date Column in Date Only format During Search ORM in Odoo 8

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

Good Day! I have this problem I have a code like this

```
tree_model = self.env['hr.reception'].search([('create_date','=',date_from)])
```

the date_from is only a date only parameter while the column create_date is datetime column I only want to format the create_date as date only format
is this possible just like in postgres

```
(create_date::date)
```

Thanks for the Help

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using date() method which will return the date format instead of datetime.

For example:

```
1. datetime.now() will result in datetime format.   
2. datetime.datetime.now().date() will result in date format.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try : create_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')